# What is the best way to export data in JSON format to SQL using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My code is as follows:

```
USE MyDb
DECLARE @json varchar(max)='
{
  "BusinessEntityID":1,
  "NationalIDNumber":"295847284",
  "JobTitle":"Chief Executive Officer",
  "BirthDate":"1969-01-29",
  "Gender":"M"
}';
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person.Person WHERE  BusinessEntityID = JSON_VALUE(@json, 'BusinessEntityID')
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 13607, Level 16, State 3, Line 14
> JSON path is not well formatted. Found unexpected character 'B' at position 0.

Comment: Well yes, `FOR JSON` is certainly one way to go. It's not clear what your question is -- what's your input, what's your output and what's not acceptable about it?

Comment: What do you mean export the data to SQL? You don't convert JSON to SQL, they aren't comparable. JSON is like a table, not the language.

Comment: have a look at the documentation of SQL server, or ask a question

Comment: What is your metric for _best_? Fewest keystrokes? Smallest memory footprint?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This question is absolutely unclear. The title suggests, that you want to **export data in JSON format** (cries for `SELECT ... FOR JSON`), while your code sample and the reflected error message look like *reading one single value from a given JSON*. To solve the error message, just correct the JPath: `JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.BusinessEntityID')`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's your question. If you need to export results from a select, you can save it as CSV and use a site like https://csvjson.com/ or https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

On the other hand, if you want to convert JSON to SQL, you can use https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-sql.htm